# UITableViewCell setFrame "bugged" when updating table

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom cell which should be spaced from the edges of the display. For that I use this:

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    frame.origin.x += kCellSidesInset;
    frame.size.width -= 2 * kCellSidesInset;
    [super setFrame:frame];
}
```

I do have a button that hides/shows the bottom view of a stacked view inside the cell. For which I use this code:

```
    - (IBAction)showCardDetails:(id)sender {
        UITableView *cellTableView = (UITableView*)[[[[sender superview] superview] superview] superview ];
        [cellTableView beginUpdates];
        self.details.hidden = !self.details.hidden;
        [cellTableView endUpdates];
//    [cellTableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
//    [cellTableView reloadData];
    }
```

However when the table is updated to reflect the change the right padding becomes allot bigger. Then when I scroll a bit it gets fixed.

As much as I could visually judge it is like 3 times. Maybe it adds two more kCellSidesInset on the right but I doubt it.

Why is this happening and how can it be fixed? Maybe it can be avoid by instead of giving inset to the cell giving it to the UITableView (I have some trouble figuring how to do this).

PS. All the code is inside the CustomCell.m. I am open for a suggestion to a better way of getting the UITableView inside the action. Should I use selector in the CustomTableViewController.m to implement the action there when the cell is added?

**EDIT**: From what I can see the re rendering of the cells goes trough three phases.
Phase one, a couple of these:

[image]

Phase two, it updates the view cells:

[image]

And here everything looks good for now. The view that I want to hide/show is hidden/shown and all is good but then some sort of cleanup breaks the layout:

[image]

Comment: Is there any problem of using autolayout instead of your setFrame?

Comment: @elk_cloner I don't know how to add inset to a cell with autolayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by refactoring the `setFrame` method to use the superview's frame of the cell as a reference point for the cell frame

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    frame.origin.x = self.superview.frame.origin.x + kCellSidesInset;
    frame.size.width = self.superview.frame.size.width - 2 * kCellSidesInset;

    [super setFrame:frame];
}
```